# Can I make a date picker limited to 3 days only?

Tags: ipad, uidatepicker

In my iPad application, it is required that the date picker shows only 3 days/dates, i.e. today, tomorrow and day after tomorrow. Is it possible? If it is then how can I do it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Best Regards

PC

Comment: The docs for that particular control should have a min/max date property documented, if there is one.  I suggest you start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maximumDate
The maximum date that a date picker can show.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *maximumDate
```

minimumDate
The minimum date that a date picker can show.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *minimumDate
```